# Android - chrome close window like animation for my layout

Tags: android, android-animation

In android 4.3 when you close the chrome window you can swipe left or right to close the window/tab. The window translates and tilts/rotates simultaneously and finally closes. I want to do something similar to my sub layout in my activity.

Comment: anybody who can answer this??? Its been long time... helllllooooo

Comment: Someone, Please help me on this. I need to get this out fast. Not able to find anything on the internet too. :(

Comment: you may use viewpager to slide it and provide it animation by interpolator